# symfony: How to set configuration parameters files for different environments?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony4, symfony-3.4

How to setup a different configuration parameters file for each environment?

At the moment parameters in `parameters.yml` are used in both `dev` and `prod` environment, but I need different parameters in order to deploy my app in prod.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put all the parameters used in your `dev` environment in a `app\config\parameters_dev.yml` file (*you need to create it*) and then import it in your `app\config\config_dev.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_dev.yml }
```

So when you work in local any parameter used in production will be overwritten by the new file with the right parameters.

**And remember to Clear the cache!**

Comment: ok I did this way, so I expect that using app.php it should use parameters in parameters.yml, and using app_dev.php it should use parameters in parameters_dev.yml. looks like the only file used is parameters_dev is used from both front controllers...

Comment: ARGH! DAMN CACHE! now works perfectly. I love you. thank you.

Comment: @user3174311 I use this type of configuration every time. In production will be only used parameters in `parameters.yml` as well as for others environments. For example you may want to have your database mirrored for testing purposes (and with different access data) and for this just create a `parameters_test.yml` and apply the same concept.