# Symfony parameters variable in variable

Tags: symfony

I work on a symfony project and I want to do something like this in my app/config/parameters.yml

```
dev.google.api.key: foo
google: %%kernel.environment%.google%
```

It not works.

I explain : I want to have the variable google to have values depending my environment (env or prod).

So I defined two variable :

```
dev.google.api.key: foo
prod.google.api.key: bar
```

I want to have my variable google to be filled with content depending on the environment. The environment is in the variable

```
%kernel.environment%
```

So if I do :

```
google: %kernel.environment%.google
```

Google is equal to "dev.google" but I want to this string to be evaluated like this %dev.google%. But %%kernel.environment%.google% not works.

An idea ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But I think you complexify your need. Do you really need to declare this parameters ? you have config_dev.yml and config_prod.yml file

Comment: Yes but a cannot accès content from config.yml on my twig files. I want to add this vars to my twig : globals. But to keep this variables in parameters to avoid adding variables in multiple files. But give up, I put my vars in config_env. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony: How to set configuration parameters files for different environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328186/symfony-how-to-set-configuration-parameters-files-for-different-environments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

in your **config_dev.yml**:

```
parameters:
    google.api.key: foo
```

in your **config_prod.yml**:

```
parameters:
    google.api.key: bar
```

in your **config.yml**:

```
google: %google.api.key%
```

---

***Or***

Create **paramater_dev.yml** with

```
parameters:
    google.api.key: foo
```

Create **paramater_prod.yml** with

```
parameters:
    google.api.key: bar
```

in your **config_dev.yml**:

```
imports:
    - { resource: paramater_dev.yml }
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

in your **config_prod.yml**:

```
imports:
    - { resource: paramater_prod.yml }
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

in your **config.yml**:

```
google: %google.api.key%
```